# Can I used much with comparative?

Tags: grammar

Can I used much with comparative? For example:

> He sings better than you
>
> He sings **much** better than you
>
> Mike is richer than you
>
> Mike is **much** richer than you?

What is the difference between the sentence where there is *much* with comparative and where there it is not

Comment: Is there some reason why you think that much is not acceptable. Have you checked in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Put it this way: if you have $900 and Mike has $1000 then

> Mike is richer than you.

But if Mike has $1000000 then

> Mike is ***much*** richer than you.

With regard to singing, if at karaoke you get very little applause and Mike gets a lot of applause then

> He sings better than you.

But if Mike's recording is played on the radio then

> He sings ***much*** better than you.